# Run a process to work on a particular function

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I got a code in C that contains main function and another function, And I made a fork to create another process. I want to make the new process perform only the function and once it finishes executing it will die.

I searched solution but I didn't find.

Comment: Have the child process call the function and `exit()` after it returns.

Comment: You exit a child process just like you exit your parent process: By calling `exit` or by returning from `main`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun()
{
     printf ("In fun\n");
     // Do your stuff
     // ....
}

int main(void)
{
   pid_t pid = fork();

   if (pid == -1) {
      perror("fork failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (pid == 0) {
      // Child process
      fun();   // Calling function in child process
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   else {
      // Parent process
      int status;
      // Wait for child
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```